# forEach Inside forEach useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, foreach, use-effect, use-state

I'm having a problem with the useEffect hook, apparently, it doesn't render the way it's used to, since my cardArticle doesn't log correctly, it only concats the las array and that's it. Here's the code:

```
  const [articles, setArticles] = useState([]);
  const [cardArticle, setCardArticle] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setArticulos(shopArticles);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    articles.forEach((article) => {
      var objects = article[0][`${Object.keys(article[0])}`];
      objects.forEach((object) => {
        setCardArticle([...cardArticle, object]);
      });
    });
  }, [articles]);
```

Here's the json from shopArticles:

```
[
  [
    {
      "Pantalones": [
        {
          "id": "pantalon1",
          "imagen": "https://www.newbalance.com.ar/media/catalog/product/cache/4/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/p/a/pantalon-mujer-new-balance-essentials-ft-sweatpant-wp83552ag_nb_40_i.jpg",
          "precio": 1250,
          "stock": 3
        },
        {
          "id": "pantalon2",
          "imagen": "https://www.newbalance.com.ar/media/catalog/product/cache/4/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/p/a/pantalon-mujer-new-balance-essentials-ft-sweatpant-wp83552ag_nb_40_i.jpg",
          "precio": 1250,
          "stock": 1
        },
        {
          "id": "pantalon3",
          "imagen": "https://www.newbalance.com.ar/media/catalog/product/cache/4/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/p/a/pantalon-mujer-new-balance-essentials-ft-sweatpant-wp83552ag_nb_40_i.jpg",
          "precio": 1250,
          "stock": 5
        },
        {
          "id": "pantalon4",
          "imagen": "https://www.newbalance.com.ar/media/catalog/product/cache/4/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/p/a/pantalon-mujer-new-balance-essentials-ft-sweatpant-wp83552ag_nb_40_i.jpg",
          "precio": 1250,
          "stock": 2
        },
        {
          "id": "pantalon5",
          "imagen": "https://www.newbalance.com.ar/media/catalog/product/cache/4/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/p/a/pantalon-mujer-new-balance-essentials-ft-sweatpant-wp83552ag_nb_40_i.jpg",
          "precio": 1250,
          "stock": 3
        },
        {
          "id": "pantalon6",
          "imagen": "https://www.newbalance.com.ar/media/catalog/product/cache/4/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/p/a/pantalon-mujer-new-balance-essentials-ft-sweatpant-wp83552ag_nb_40_i.jpg",
          "precio": 1250,
          "stock": 0
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "Remeras": [
        {
          "id": "remera1",
          "imagen": "https://www.newbalance.com.ar/media/catalog/product/cache/4/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/p/a/pantalon-mujer-new-balance-essentials-ft-sweatpant-wp83552ag_nb_40_i.jpg",
          "precio": 1250,
          "stock": 3
        },
        {
          "id": "remera2",
          "imagen": "https://www.newbalance.com.ar/media/catalog/product/cache/4/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/p/a/pantalon-mujer-new-balance-essentials-ft-sweatpant-wp83552ag_nb_40_i.jpg",
          "precio": 1250,
          "stock": 1
        },
        {
          "id": "remera3",
          "imagen": "https://www.newbalance.com.ar/media/catalog/product/cache/4/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/p/a/pantalon-mujer-new-balance-essentials-ft-sweatpant-wp83552ag_nb_40_i.jpg",
          "precio": 1250,
          "stock": 5
        },
        {
          "id": "remera4",
          "imagen": "https://www.newbalance.com.ar/media/catalog/product/cache/4/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/p/a/pantalon-mujer-new-balance-essentials-ft-sweatpant-wp83552ag_nb_40_i.jpg",
          "precio": 1250,
          "stock": 2
        },
        {
          "id": "remera5",
          "imagen": "https://www.newbalance.com.ar/media/catalog/product/cache/4/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/p/a/pantalon-mujer-new-balance-essentials-ft-sweatpant-wp83552ag_nb_40_i.jpg",
          "precio": 1250,
          "stock": 3
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "Calzado": [
        {
          "id": "calzado1",
          "imagen": "https://www.newbalance.com.ar/media/catalog/product/cache/4/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/p/a/pantalon-mujer-new-balance-essentials-ft-sweatpant-wp83552ag_nb_40_i.jpg",
          "precio": 1250,
          "stock": 3
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "Vestido": [
        {
          "id": "vestido1",
          "imagen": "https://www.newbalance.com.ar/media/catalog/product/cache/4/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/p/a/pantalon-mujer-new-balance-essentials-ft-sweatpant-wp83552ag_nb_40_i.jpg",
          "precio": 1250,
          "stock": 3
        },
        {
          "id": "vestido2",
          "imagen": "https://www.newbalance.com.ar/media/catalog/product/cache/4/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/p/a/pantalon-mujer-new-balance-essentials-ft-sweatpant-wp83552ag_nb_40_i.jpg",
          "precio": 1250,
          "stock": 3
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
]
```

if there's any chance to improve my code, please let my know, i don't know what else to do.

Answer (score 0):

calling a setter from useState (setCardArticle) launch a refresh of the component with the actual known state (before the forEach finish)

you should replace

```
objects.forEach((object) => {
  setCardArticle([...cardArticle, object]);
});
```

by

```
setCardArticle([...cardArticle, ...articles.map(article=>article[0][`${Object.keys(article[0])}`])]);
```

Comment: Thank you for responding, but that didn't work. The state of cardArticle keeps giving me empty, i don't know why